# Using loop to identify different value for all columns within same id row in R

Tags: r

This is a further question regarding to one of my previous questions. The link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72968349/how-to-detect-the-multivalued-observation-for-each-id-in-dataset.). That question asked how to identify the different values within the same id rows for single column. But now, suppose I have dataset called df and it has multiple columns to check, in other words, I would like to do the similar thing but for all columns instead of specific one column.

The simulated dataset is here:

```
hhid<-c("hh001","hh001","hh001","hh002","hh002","hh002","hh003","hh003", "hh004","hh004")
gender<-c("m","m","m","m","m","m","f","f","f","f")
age<-c(12,22,12,11,11,11,18,23,9,9)
waterID<-c("W1","W2","W1","W7","W7","W7","W9","W10","W19","W19")
df_dup<-data.frame(hhid, gender, age, waterID)
```

```
hhid   gender  age   waterID
hh001     m      12  W1
hh001     m      22  W2
hh001     m      12  W1
hh002     m      11  W7
hh002     m      11  W7
hh002     m      11  W7
hh003     f      18  W9
hh003     f      23  W10        
hh004     f      9   W19
hh004     f      9   W19
...
```

Now in the dataset, there are two type of duplicates. One is **completed duplicates** such as hh002 and hh004.These are completed duplicate for all colunns.
Another is **partial duplicates**, such as hh001, hh003, they have different values in col age and waterID. Those have duplicated id but also have differences in some columns.
For this dataset, I want to do with a R code:

Create a new column (say.duptype) to mark type of duplicate, if it is a completed duplicate, then duptype=cdup, if it is partial duplicate, then the duptype=pdup. So later, I can decide which type of duplicate row I need to keep in dataset, and which I can filter them out.

I have very rough and immature thoughts for this given the reference of my previous question.

like first, I may need to extract the whole columns names, and save as vector;

```
z<-colnames(df_dup)
```

then I use loop to detect within hhid, if their values in all columns are the same, if so, mark cdup in duptype column, otherwise, mark pdup in duptype column.

```
for(i in z){
   dfnew<-df_dup%>%
         group_by(hhid)%>%
         mutate(duptype=if_else(any(i!=lag(i), pdup, cdup))))%>%
         }
```

But apparently, the code I wrote is far away from the result I expected. I appreciate it if anyone could help me to achieve this. Thanks a lot~~!

Comment: As with you first question, using dput on your dataframe and pasting the output will help everyone to able to work with your data and speed up a response.

Comment: @Peter_Evan, I also remind users when they need to provide unambiguous sample data in an easily consumable formats. This, while not unambiguous per se and not `dput`, is easily consumed/used: copy and run `dat <- read.table("clipboard", header=TRUE)` (on windows/linux, macos needs `pipe("pbCopy")` I think).

Comment: @Peter_Evan Cannot provide the original dataset, but updated the simulated dataset for this post. Thanks for reminding me for that. :)

Comment: See `?duplicated`; e.g. [Finding ALL duplicate rows, including "elements with smaller subscripts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/finding-all-duplicate-rows-including-elements-with-smaller-subscripts). `c("cd", "pd")[df_dup$hhid %in% df_dup$hhid[!(duplicated(df_dup) | duplicated(df_dup, fromLast = TRUE))] + 1]`

Comment: @Rstudyer see @Henrik answer in the comments. Just make sure to assign it to a new field. Something like: `df_dup$dup_type <- c("cd", "pd")[df_dup$hhid %in% df_dup$hhid[!(duplicated(df_dup) | duplicated(df_dup, fromLast = TRUE))] + 1]`